# How to access full <div> id value based on query selector partial select

Tags: jquery-selectors, bootstrap-modal

I have an html view that has multiple bootstrap modals.  Each modal has an id that is prefixed with a static name and suffixed with a name of an image which is just random string (i.e. `id="image-0jM5v1sh2tAQ7BVPomZl"`, `id="image-0WzpWwCFbjSWD5im7It8"`, `id="image-0xnd7RvHOxrLxhCfHupp"`)

I want a function to run each time the user clicks to open any of these modals. So I have this code:

```
$("div[id*='image-']").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // How do I assign this image variable a value of the name of the full <div> id?
    var image = // I want this to equal for example "image-0WzpWwCFbjSWD5im7It8' but it needs to be dynamic based on which modal the user opened.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div[id*='image-']").on('click', function() {
  var image = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
  alert(image);
})
```

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-0jM5v1sh2tAQ7BVPomZl">test1</div>
<div id="image-0WzpWwCFbjSWD5im7It8">test2</div>
<div id="image-0xnd7RvHOxrLxhCfHupp">test3</div>
```